# How do I protect command output in eshell and REPL buffers?

Tags: eshell, repl

Since command outputs are easily mutable, I have to be careful when I work with eshell and REPL buffers.

Is there a way to protect them?

Comment: could you let know if Tobias' answer statisied you?

Comment: I was waiting for a more complete answer, but his answer works for eshell. Since no other answer was coming, I chose his answer.

Comment: Do you mean the lisp-scratch buffer by `repl` buffer?

Comment: @Tobias In my case, it is REPL buffers launched by `cider-jack-in` and `nodejs-repl`. But, I want everything except the current input line on all REPL buffers and all shell buffers to be immutable against keyboard inputs.

Comment: `nodejs-repl` is derived from `comint`-mode -- **as it should be**. Therefore, the added section on `comint` in the already existing answer should work. It looks like this is not the case for `cider` because `cider` is not based on `comint` but they do their own stuff for process communication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modes that communicate with external shells should inherit from `comint` mode. `eshell` is an exception w.r.t this principle since it emulates almost all commands on elisp-base. First, setting output read-only is described for `eshell` afterwards for `comint`-based modes.

### `eshell`

The following lisp snippet demonstrates the usage of `eshell-output-filter-functions` for setting the output read-only.
It is not very sophisticated and not thoroughly tested.

```lisp
(defun eshell-interactive-output-readonly ()
  "Make output of interactive commands in eshell read-only.
This should be the last entry in eshell-output-filter-functions!"
  (let ((end eshell-last-output-end))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char end)
      (end-of-line 0)
      (setq end (point)))
    (when (< eshell-last-output-block-begin end)
      (put-text-property eshell-last-output-block-begin end 'read-only "Read-only interactive eshell output"))))

(defun eshell-make-interactive-output-readonly ()
  (add-hook 'eshell-output-filter-functions 'eshell-interactive-output-readonly 'append))

(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook 'eshell-make-interactive-output-readonly)
```

---

### `comint` based modes:

It looks like one cannot use `comint-output-filter-functions` for setting the command output read-only in `comint`-based modes.
The reason is that `comint-output-filter` sets unconditionally the `rear-nonsticky` text property to `t`. Therefore you can insert text into the output despite of the `read-only`-property even if already existing output characters cannot be modified.

The only chance to protect the output is an `after`-advice for `comint-output-filter`. The following code-snippet demonstrates the principle.

```lisp
(defadvice comint-output-filter (after output-readonly activate)
  "Set last process output read-only."
  (add-text-properties comint-last-output-start (line-end-position 0)
               '(read-only "Process output is read-only."
                   rear-nonsticky (inhibit-line-move-field-capture))))
```

Comment: Notably, a lot of these modes fail to take advantage of the [fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Fields.html) feature of Emacs. For example, if I was writing eshell, I would propertize the prompt with `'field 'prompt`, the user-typed input with `'field 'input`, and command output with `'field 'output`. This wouldn't be perfect in the edge cases (an interactive external command which prompts for its own input wouldn't get detected by eshell, for example), but it's far better than no fields at all. Even something as little as tagging the prompt with a field is huge.

Comment: The relevant tie-in to this answer is that if these modes actually annotated the different pieces of text, then the solution to marking pieces read-only becomes more elegant - more universally reusable and composable - because then we could scan the text for the relevant field properties, reducing the mode-specific logic. And incidentally, for example in `eshell` at least, we *can* inject a `field` property to the prompt and add `field` to its `rear-nonsticky` property, by overriding `eshell-prompt-function` (and disabling the default prompt highlighting) or advising `eshell-emit-prompt`.